# Testing a generated curried function with Scala Test

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm having hard times trying to create a Scala Test to checks this function:

```
def curry[A,B,C](f: (A,B) => C): A => (B => C) =
  a => b => f(a,b)
```

The first thought I had was to validate if given a function `fx` passed into `curry(fx)` function, will return a curried version of it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to test it, is to pass different `f`'s to it and see if you are getting back the function you expect. For example, you can test an f that returns the arguments as a tuple:

```
def f(x: String, y: Int) = (x, y)

curry(f)("4")(7) must be(("4", 7))
```

IMO, testing it for a few different functions `f` and for a few different `a` and `b` would be more than sufficiently assuring that something as trivial as this works as intended.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense! Thanks ;)